# Polymorphism: Polymorphic types for the same member

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Suppose we have classes `Derived*` (here `*` means distinguishing suffixes), which are derived from class `Base`. Now a member should be added into class `Base`, the type of which needs to be differently inherited of its own type in  derived classes. It could be represented as following (in logic) in c++:

```
class Base {
protected:
    BaseType m_member;
};

class Derived1 : Base {
    DerivedType1 m_member; // this member should be the same member in base class
};

class Derived2 : Base {
    DerivedType2 m_member;
};

class BaseType {
protected:
    virtual void foo();
};

class DerivedType1 : BaseType { ... };
class DerivedType2 : BaseType { ... };
```

Here `m_member` in `Derived1` is meant to be exactly `m_member` in `Base`, with only types changed (and even the new type is inherited from the old type). I know that this piece of code does not do what I need (here `m_member`s in each class are not related with each other at all), what do I need to do?

I've considered using `boost::static_visitor` (and without creating new classes for `Base`) for this case. However, derived classes *needs* to be classes.

Now my temporary solution for this problem is that derived classes hold this member of the same type as the base classes, but handle this member in different ways. Source:

```
class Base {
protected:
    BaseType m_member;
};

class Derived1 : Base {
public:
    Derived1() :
        m_member(DerivedType1()) { /* ... */ }
};
```

So, any better choices? E.g. pointers?

Comment: `m_member(DerivedType1())` probably does not do what you want. It slices the `BaseType` part out of the `DerivedType1` and discards the `DerivedType1` parts.

Comment: You might try to use class templates to achieve what you want.

Comment: it seems like you want polymorphism/inheritance to do something that it does not, but it is not perfectly clear what you actually want to achieve. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Better focus on what you want to do instead of describing the solution you have in mind